# Responsive Horizontal Menu without jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, menu, responsive-design, navbar

I'm looking for a responsive horizontal menu that collapse dynamically the items that doesn't fit in a "more" section of the menu.
Pretty exactly like this example:
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Horizontal-Nav-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS

Since I'm going to use it in a static generated offline page, I don't want the whole jQuery implementation in the code and looking for a simpler solution, doing the same but with only a little or without JS but with pure CSS.

Is this possible? Or do I have to use jQuery for achieving it?

Comment: No, not possible with CSS. CSS doesn't "know" when the items don't fit/ where the breakpoint is. You'll need JS/ jQuery for that.

Comment: @LinkinTED Which is why you have to program them in manually ;) Check my answer.

Comment: @Rvervuurt Yeah, exactly... It's a solution indeed. But not pretty... JS gives a more flexible solution imo. Great work tho :)

Comment: Of course! I would also recommend JS or jQuery. Especially if it's offline, where you can just store the library locally. But my answer should be functional. Trying to set up a fiddle right now.

Comment: Yea, pretty is different (since you basically have to have two menus), but it works @LinkinTED http://jsfiddle.net/dynnc8bf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Answer updated, fiddle added in bottom!]**

It is very possible with pure CSS, the question is just if it's going to be pretty. Since CSS can't know when it breaks a `div` (it just does it), you have to put these breakpoints in manually. Since you are talking about an offline page, it's probably no problem to keep track of this manually.

You're probably familiar with `@media` rules in CSS. You're also probably used to putting 2 or 3 of them in your page to catch some different resolutions and display your webpage according to those resolutions.

A solution for your above problem would be to add one `@media`-breakpoint for every menu-point.

Do you have 6 items and the 6th falls off at 600px, then you add the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /*your CSS here to hide menu point 6 in the dropdown*/
}
```

Continuing on the above example: if the 5th menu point would wrap to the next line at 500px, you add another breakpoint:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    /*your CSS here to hide menu point 6 AND 5 in the dropdown*/
}
```

You just continue this process until you have the menu react exactly how you want it to.

Edit: I have made a pretty bad-looking Fiddle, but it's functional and you can probably use it as source material. There are two menus and depending on the width of the window, it hides or shows items.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dynnc8bf/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the support - I realized it with basic CSS: http://codepen.io/konradmd/pen/zGyLaX

Comment: It is fully responsive for mobiles, and includes media queries for widths of 330px and 768px.The CodePen version is a fully responsive horizontal menu in pure CSS.  I thought the OP might find it helpful. There do not seem to be many around.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible *yet* (that is, unless you use a fixed menu item width).

In CSS Level 4 you have a new thing called [regions](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-regions-1/) there is an example from [Razvan Caliman](http://goo.gl/vHlHxM) [here](http://goo.gl/3GFfT4) (you can check this out in [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html)). But until then I'm afraid javascript is the best solution.